# How can I look up how much ASIC Miner has mined in the last week?

Tags: blockchain.info, block, mining-profitability, hashpower

I can see a list of their most recent blocks here: http://blockchain.info/blocks/ASICMiner, but is it possible to get aggregate numbers over a given time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.asicminercharts.com/live/ keeps track of the total amount stored in the mining wallet, as well as hashing power over time (Take the /live off to see historical charts).